# Adding an external XML file to a C# project

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have been looking for a way to add a pre-existing external XML file into a project.
I have come across ways of creating an XML and attaching it to the project but none for pre-existing XML files to be attached.

I have tried a path name combined with

```
  xmlDoc.Load("pathname");
```

but \ cause an 'Unrecognised escape sequence'

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Show your code... Can't tell you why you're getting that error without the actual code.

Comment: What are you actually using for your pathname? Are you remembering to use double slashes for folder separators, or use the `@` key at the beginning?

Comment: You can prefix a string with `@` to prevent escaping: `string path = @"c:\temp\somefile.xml";`

Comment: I was missing out the @ to begin the pathname. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do as stated below:

```
xmlDoc.Load(@"c:\temp\file.xml");
```

or you can use the double slash as so:

```
xmlDoc.Load("c:\\temp\\file.xml");
```

Either will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

When calling an external file to the project remember to add an @ in front of the path name string. As stated by Slippery Pete and gunr2171 it prevents the escaping error that was happening in the above code.

In this case, the following code worked:

```
xmlDoc.Load(@"c:\temp\file.xml");
```